# Use form naming to reach json data in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following input name: `dynamic[elements][1][slider][image1]`

When performing an ajax call, a json response with settings and its value is returned.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/get/settings',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {

        });
```

How can i get the value of `dynamic[elements][1][slider][image1]` the easiest way? It works to get the value like this:

```
data.dynamic.elements[1].slider.image1
```

So:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/get/settings',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
               console.log(data.dynamic.elements[1].slider.image1);
        });
```

But isn't their any better way of getting the value? The only identifier I have to get the value, is the name of the input field which is `dynamic[elements][1][slider][image1]`. So i would need to extract this string and put it together as `data.dynamic.elements[1].slider.image1` to then make it a dynamic variable somehow (to finally get the value)?

Example ajax response:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "dynamic": {
        "elements": [
            {
                "title": {
                    "title": "Our beautiful topic"
                }
            },
            {
                "slider": {
                    "image1": "5zw3ucypzp3qham.png",
                    "image1_link": "hellor"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: show your example  ajax response data

Comment: Can you put an `id` on the field ?

Comment: I cant put a id on the field. Will update with a example ajax response

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to write a generic function for the purpose of retrieving data from object. The function should look something like below. Though the function may not be foolproof but should be enough for proof-of-concept.

```
function getObjectData(target, path) {

     // if the path is not in dot notation first convert 
     if (path.indexOf(".") == -1)
        path = path.replace(/\[/g, ".").replace(/\]/g, "");

    var parts = path.split(".");
    return parts.reduce(function (acc, currentVal) {
        return acc ? (acc[currentVal] || undefined) : acc;
    }, target);
}

//usage
getObjectData(data, "dynamic.elements.0.slider.image1"); //undefined
getObjectData(data, "dynamic.elements.1.slider.image1"); //5zw3ucypzp3qham.png
getObjectData(data, "dynamic[elements][1][slider][image1]"); //5zw3ucypzp3qham.png
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks your contribution. Seems like this is reverse of what I would like to achieve.. I would like to pass dynamic[elements][1][slider][image1] to get the value of dynamic.elements.1.slider.image1 in the data object. Hope you understand!

Comment: @Karem You can simply replace the brackets with dots. My updated answer shows a way to do that.